# Are there succesful solid fueled internal combustion engines?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Are there any succesful solid fueled internal combustion engines? Particularily, ones that produce shaft power (not rockets and not ramjets)

Comment: Steam rollers worked quite well - solid fuel as in wood or coal but wood may be more sustainable...

Comment: I don't think steam engines count. Doesn't internal combustion mean it burns in the pistons?

Answer (score 4):

over the years, people have tried running ICE's on *coal dust*. It is possible, but it's difficult to meter the dust into the engine's intake to get the proper mixture, and it's difficult to transport the dust from a fuel tank into the engine compartment.